# Deploying jaeger on AWS ECS with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ecs, jaeger

How should I go about deploying Jaeger on AWS ECS with Elasticsearch as backend? Is it a good idea to use the Jaeger all in one image or should I use separate images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I didn’t find any official jaeger reference to this, I think the jaeger all in one image is not intended for use in production. It makes one container a single point of failure, making it better to use separate containers for each jaeger component(if one is down from some reason - others can continue to operate).

I have recently written a [blog post](https://www.aspecto.io/blog/how-to-deploy-jaeger-on-aws-a-comprehensive-step-by-step-guide) about hosting jaeger on AWS with AWS Elasticsearch (OpenSearch) service. While it is done with all-in-one, it is still useful to get the general idea of how to go about this.

Just to generally outline the process (described in detail in the post):

1. Create AWS Elasticsearch cluster
2. Create an ECS Cluster (running on ec2)
3. Create an ECS Task Definition, configured with a jaeger all-in-one image with the elasticsearch url from the step 1
4. Create an ECS Service that runs the created task definition
5. Make sure security groups on your EC2 allow access to jaeger ports as described [here](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.25/getting-started/)
6. Send spans to your jaeger endpoint via OpenTelemetry SDK
7. View your spans via the hosted jaeger UI (your-ec2-url:16686)

Answer (score 1):

The all in one is a useful tool in development to test your work locally.

For deployment it is very limiting. Ideally to handle a potentially large volume of traffic you will want to scale parts of your infrastructure.

I would recommend deploying multiple jaeger-collectors, configured to write to the ES cluster. Then you can configure jaeger-agents running as a sidecar to each app or service broadcasting telemetry info. These agents can be configured to forward to one of a list of collectors adding some extra resilience.